# How to simplify this routes.rb code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's my current routes.rb code:

```
Mysite::Application.routes.draw do
  get "pages/home"

  get "pages/about"

  get "pages/resume"

  get "pages/contact"

  root :to => "pages#home"

  match "/about", to: "pages#about"
  match "/resume", to: "pages#resume"
  match "/contact", to: "pages#contact"
end
```

Is there a way to simplify my routing of the root directory to the pages controller? Instead of matching every single route off the root directory to a pages controller action, could I instead match the entire root directory to the pages controller itself?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first four `get`s. Your `root` and `match` declarations will work just fine.

```
Mysite::Application.routes.draw do

  match "/about", to: "pages#about"
  match "/resume", to: "pages#resume"
  match "/contact", to: "pages#contact"
  root :to => "pages#home"

end
```

Comment: Note that in Rails 4 there will no longer be `match`. You can instead use `get` if/when you make that leap.

Comment: on rails 4 you could use `match` if you supply `:via`

Answer (score 0):

If you want that path like "pages/about" then

```
Mysite::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "pages#home"

  scope '/pages' do
    match "/about", to: "pages#about"
    match "/resume", to: "pages#resume"
    match "/contact", to: "pages#contact"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to route the **entire** root directory to the pages controller, you can draw a **cath all** route:

```
  match '/*path', to: 'pages#show'
```

doing so at the end of your routes catches all requests not previeously defined.
In your pages#show you can inspect the path and try to find matching pages
i.e.

```
  search =  params[:path].split('/').last
```

gets the last part of the path and

```
  @page = Page.find_by_titel_or_id search
```

tries to find an matching page by title. (So done by CMS like refinery_cms)

Answer (score 0):

```
Mysite::Application.routes.draw do
# Layout
  resources :pages do
    get 'about' => 'pages#about', :on => :collection
    get 'resume' => 'pages#resume', :on => :collection
    get 'contact' => 'pages#contact', :on => :collection
  end
  match 'About' => 'pages#about', :as => :About
  match 'Resume' => 'pages#resume', :as => :Resume
  match 'Contact' => 'pages#contact', :as => :Contact
  root :to => "pages#home"
end
```

Now you can use directly this matches like

```
<a href='/Contact'>Contact Us</a>
```